# UITableViewCellReorderControl default color wrong since Xcode 11

Tags: objective-c, ios13, xcode11

I encounter UITableViewCellReorderControl color become same as cell color, this symptom confuse me wonder the UITableViewCellReorderControl disappears.

I add background color for UITableViewCellReorderControl to confirm it real exist.

[image]

I guess this symptom because the iOS 13 dark mode, but I can't fix it even focus the overrideUserInterfaceStyle to UIUserInterfaceStyleLight.

Is there any idea or experience for it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` solved my problem.

Note that setting it to `UIUserInterfaceStyle.light` means light background and dark accessory color.

It seems like in your example `UIUserInterfaceStyle.dark` would be the correct value.